# Obtaining userId with UberRUSH access token

Tags: uber-api

I have a question regarding UberRUSH three-legged-oauth and webhooks.

We are developing multi-tenant application that will act on behalf of UberRUSH users.
We are implementing three-legged-oauth flow, and we want to use webhooks to update delivery statuses.

In webhooks documentation (https://developer.uber.com/docs/deliveries/guides/webhooks) I read that UberRUSH event will contain information about delivery id (`meta.resource_id`) and user id (`meta.user_id`).

As we internally store our entities in separate tenants (separate tenant per UberRUSH user) we need to map event's `user_id` to our tenant name. 
The only way I can think about for building such map, is based on user's access token that we keep. We can decode it (JWT) and read it's `sub` property  (Subject), as I assume it contains user's id.

My question is, is it valid and safe (can we rely on it and it will not change in predictable future) to obtain user's id that way, or maybe there is simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the 3-legged-oauth, one simpler way to do this is to use the [/me endpoint](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/me-get) from the Riders API. That would provide you with the following user data:

```
{
  "picture": "https://d1w2poirtb3as9.cloudfront.net/f3be498cb0bbf570aa3d.jpeg",
  "first_name": "Uber",
  "last_name": "Developer",
  "uuid": "f4a416e3-6016-4623-8ec9-d5ee105a6e27",
  "rider_id": "8OlTlUG1TyeAQf1JiBZZdkKxuSSOUwu2IkO0Hf9d2HV52Pm25A0NvsbmbnZr85tLVi-s8CckpBK8Eq0Nke4X-no3AcSHfeVh6J5O6LiQt5LsBZDSi4qyVUdSLeYDnTtirw==",
  "email": "uberdevelopers@gmail.com",
  "mobile_verified": true,
  "promo_code": "uberd340ue"
}
```

With the uuid, rider_id, and email you'd get identifying props for the user. Keep in mind, you need to request the `profile` scope during auth to being able to make the call to /me.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This approach would work but it will cost us one additional call (that can fail). If we just need userId, isn't solution with decoding access token simpler and more safe? The only downside of this solution is that it is maybe not recommended by Uber to do it this way?

Comment: The docs state that [the access token length might change over time](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/authentication/introduction#debugging-authentication-errors). While there are no plans to make this change, there is also no guarantee that the JWT format will stay as it is